# Display output in HTML format by perl

Tags: html, perl

I have a hashmap with some information(key and value) in a perl file. I want to display them in HTML output and each displayed (key, value) will link to something. When I click the link then there will be some information there. 
Anyone suggests me how can I do that. Is this similar to creating a CGI file and use CGI.pm? I will update more detail on this question later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the data you're trying to display, something like [HTML::Table](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Table) may be useful if you want to display it in tabular format and don't want the drugery of assembling the appropriate HTML yourself.

For instance, you could do something like:

```
my $table = HTML::Table->new(-columns => 2);
for my $key (sort keys %hash) {
    $table->addRow($key, $hash{$key});
}
$table->print;
```

Also, there is a free [Beginning Perl](http://www.perl.org/books/beginning-perl/) book available online, which has a [chapter devoted to CGI scripts](http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fblob.perl.org%2Fbooks%2Fbeginning-perl%2F3145_Chap12.pdf), along with a lot of other useful information.

If this is more than just a simple one-off script, you might also wish to consider using one of the many [Perl web frameworks](http://www.perlfoundation.org/perl5/index.cgi?web_frameworks) like [Dancer](http://www.perldancer.org/), [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/), [Mojo](http://mojolicious.org/) etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the excellent [CGI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI) module to render HTML content for you, even if you are not processing CGI forms (i.e. use the module only on output, rather than also for input processing):

```
use CGI;

my $q = CGI->new;
my @html_list = map {
     $q->li($_ . ": " . $hash{$_};
} keys %hash;

print $q->ul($q->li({-type=>'foo'}, @html_list);
```